# How to access data within variable? Error: undefined method

Tags: ruby, exchangewebservices

Printing the contents of a variable gives me a bunch of data. 
I want to access part of that data, but get an error.

I'm using Viewpoint::EWS and am successfully accessing the data I need.

```
calendaritems = folder.find_items({:folder_id => folder.folder_id, :calendar_view => {:start_date => sd.rfc3339(), :end_date => ed.rfc3339()}})
calendaritems.each do |event|
...
end
```

Printing the variable "event", I can see the data I need: "date_time_stamp" (or "appointment_reply_time").

```
#<Viewpoint::EWS::Types::CalendarItem:0x00005652b332dfa0
@ews_item=
:date_time_stamp=>{:text=>"2019-03-18T12:01:49Z"},
:appointment_reply_time=>{:text=>"2019-03-18T13:01:55+01:00"},
```

However, trying to access using "event.date_time_stamp" (or "event.appointment_reply_time") leads to the error

```
undefined method `date_time_stamp' for <Viewpoint::EWS::Types::CalendarItem:0x00005622f83c3d38> (NoMethodError)
```

Here's the code:

```rb
calendaritems = folder.find_items({:folder_id => folder.folder_id, :calendar_view => {:start_date => sd.rfc3339(), :end_date => ed.rfc3339()}})
calendaritems.each do |event|
  if event.recurring?
      puts "#{event.date_time_stamp} | #{(event.start-event.date_time_stamp).to_i} | #{event.organizer.email_address}"
      if (event.start-event.date_time_stamp).to_i == reminderDays
           executeSomething()
      end
  end
end
```

I'm looking through recurring appointments for a resource within a week. Since those will be silently dropped after a year, the plan is to set up a system to remind people that this will happen, so they can rebook the resource.

At first I tried using the creation date of the appointment (event.date_time_created), which works as expected, but then noticed, that people can update their appointments, thus resetting the 1 year timer.

That's why I also need the date of the last update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug output you supplied says that `event` variable has an attribute "ews_item" and then it has a hash with an attribute "date_time_stamp", so try `event.ews_item[:date_time_stamp]`